# How to prevent Windows from 10 making its bootloader the default and skipping rEFInd

Tags: grub, uefi, bootloader, refind

I have an Alienware X51 R3 to dual boot Linux and Windows 10. I use refind as my boot manager, but Windows keeps skipping it and booting directly to Windows 10. I've been having this problem for years, and usually I follow one method described on Rod Smith's (rEFInd creator) site: overwrite the Windows 10 efi file with the rEFInd one. This works quite well, but every time there is a Windows update, the boot manager is restored, and it is a total pain in the ass. It's not the first time that I mess the files while repairing it and have to recover.

Also, I have already tried:

```
bcdedit /set {current} recoveryenabled No
```

and:

```
bcedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi
```

and (from linux):

```
sudo refind refind-mkdefault
```

and even setting a UEFI password, using EasyUEFI, EasyBCD and efibootmgr, rEFInd keeps being skipped. Is there anything new I can try?

Comment: If your computer doesn't follow the UEFI standard there's nothing you can do. Apparently it doesn't because if it did you wouldn't need rEFInd or the replacement workaround, you would use Grub as usual and the Windows updates wouldn't change it unless for feature updates but it would be easy as selecting the Linux OS entry again. If it keeps overriding the user selected boot order to Windows it doesn't comply with UEFI specifications.

Comment: Did you try changing the boot order in the BIOS / UEFI? There may be a way in there to change the priority to use the Linux bootloader before windows.

Comment: @HeroCC I did, but there is no such option.

Comment: @derkomai For sure there is. What I commented above is another issue affecting a small percentage of laptops. Again, in those cases, no matter what the user selects the UEFI keeps resetting it to "Windows bootloader". If you haven't noticed the boot order then I suspect you don't quite understand how UEFI works and *maybe* yours does not have that problem, it's just not being used correctly.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/228069/129271

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia what I meant is that in the BIOS/UEFI setup, there is no useful option apart from Windows Bootloader. Yes, of course I can change my boot priority to boot first from my usb, but there is only one loader detected: the Windows one.

Comment: If you correctly installed the Linux OS in UEFI mode you must have an entry for that OS. Also keep in mind drive order and boot order isn't the same. In the drive order the first should always be the one containing the EFI partition. From there the firmware reads the bootloader information and the boot order is a different field/setting. Try selecting "Windows" and press Enter. You should see a list of all the bootloaders including rEFInd. If you don't see your specific Linux bootloader then it was incorrectly installed (legacy) and rEFInd is acting as a "gateway" bootloader.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Linux is installed in UEFI mode. I've been managing its efi files for years, as stated above. Also, I can list /sys/firmware/efi and the BIOS/EFI setup clearly states UEFI mode. When I installed the OS, I had to change it from Legacy. When I select "Windows" as you say, it does no show any list. It stays the same and will boot W10. The only way I have to access the loader list (this is what I currently do) is pressing F12 while booting. There both loaders appear and I select rEFInd to boot Linux. But I can't make this the default option, that's the problem: it is always manual.

Comment: It sounds like you have a really odd system then in terms of firmware.  All of the braindead ones I've seen that only let you use the Windows bootloader as the default had no boot menu (so the F12 to select Linux method you seem to have working would not work on them).  I'll pretty much guarantee though that it's the firmware devs trying to be 'helpful' and protect you from boot-time malware.